# how to take snapshot in mapbox ios sdk of full map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

/** @name Capturing Snapshots of the Map View */

/** Take a snapshot of the map view. 
By default, the overlay containing any visible annotations is also captured.
@return An image depicting the map view. */

```
- (UIImage *)takeSnapshot;
```

/** Take a snapshot of the map view.

@param includeOverlay Whether to include the overlay containing any visible annotations.

@return An image depicting the map view. */

```
- (UIImage *)takeSnapshotAndIncludeOverlay:(BOOL)includeOverlay;
```

Comment: this method only take visible screen snapshot but i need full map snap shot........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on which zoom level you are at. If it is the furthest zoomed out possibly (somewhere from `z0-2`, depending on device size), the world will be `256`, `512`, or `1024px` on a side. If it's zoomed in much further, say to street level at `z17`, you are talking about `2 ^ 17 * 256` or `33,554,432px` on each side of the image. This is why maps are drawn tiled and why this functionality isn't built in by default.

Answer (score 5):

Actually You can use a method called *takeSnapshot* in a **RMMapView** it returns an *UIImage* so you can use it for whatever you want, here is an example blurring my snapshot

```
-(UIImage*) performScreenshotAndBlur
{
    UIImage *blurImage = self.mapView.takeSnapshot;
    blurImage = [blurImage applyBlurWithRadius:10 tintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.067 green:0.067 blue:0.067 alpha:0.2] saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
    return blurImage;
}
```

Comment: yes,but image size is more than screen so hidden map does not show in screenshot. i want to take full map snapshot...........which is hidden in Scrollview......